# Как получить все h2 и входящие в него h3?

Tags: jquery

Есть такая вот разметка страницы:

```html
<h2>1</h2>
.....
<h3>1.1</h3>
.....
<h3>1.2</h3>
.....
<h2>2</h2>
....
<h3>2.1</h3>

и тд.
```

Мне нужно получить массив вида:

```
1: 1.1, 1.2
2: 2.1
и т.д.
```

То есть получить нужно h2 и все h3 до нового h2

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с объектом на выходе:

```js
function getContent() {
  const orderedElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('*')] // проверить влияние на быстродействие
    .filter((element) => ~['H2', 'H3'].indexOf(element.tagName));

  let key;
  return orderedElements.reduce((result, element) => {
    if (element.tagName === 'H2') {
      key = element.innerText;
      result[key] = [];
    } else {
      result[key].push(element.innerText);
    }
    return result;
  }, {});
}

console.log(getContent());
```

```html
<h2>1</h2>
<h3>1.1</h3>
<h3>1.2</h3>
<h2>2</h2>
<h3>2.1</h3>
<h3>2.2</h3>
<h2>3</h2>
<h3>3.1</h3>
<h3>3.2</h3>
```

И вариант с массивом на выходе:

```js
function getContent() {
  const orderedElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('*')] // проверить влияние на быстродействие
    .filter((element) => ~['H2', 'H3'].indexOf(element.tagName));

  let group;
  return orderedElements.reduce((result, element) => {
    if (element.tagName === 'H2') {
      group = [];
      result.push(group);
    } else {
      group.push(element.innerText);
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
}

console.log(getContent());
```

```html
<h2>1</h2>
<h3>1.1</h3>
<h3>1.2</h3>
<h2>2</h2>
<h3>2.1</h3>
<h3>2.2</h3>
<h2>3</h2>
<h3>3.1</h3>
<h3>3.2</h3>
```

Мой вариант:

```js
function getContent() {
  const orderedElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('*')] // проверить влияние на быстродействие
    .filter((element) => ~['H2', 'H3'].indexOf(element.tagName));

  let key;
  let index = 0;
  return orderedElements.reduce((result, element) => {
    if (element.tagName === 'H2') {
      index++;
      key = element.innerText;
      result[index] = {
        key,
        child: []
      };
    } else {
      result[index].child.push(element.innerText);
    }
    return result;
  }, {});
}

console.log(getContent());
```

```html
<h2>A</h2>
<h3>1.1</h3>
<h3>1.2</h3>
<h2>B</h2>
<h3>2.1</h3>
<h3>2.2</h3>
<h2>C</h2>
<h3>3.1</h3>
<h3>3.2</h3>
```

Comment: супер, огромное спасибо. подскажите такой момент еще, а как сделать чтобы сортировка полученного массива шла в таком же порядке как он в html идет. например тут в вашем примере все как надо, потому что цифры тут, а вот с текстом по другому сортирует

Comment: Вариант с массивом на выходе имеет оригинальную сортировку, как раз такую как вы написали в вопросе. Но в этом случаи теряются значения из h2. Возможно вам надо какой-то какой-то другой вид объекта на выходе?

Comment: Я добавил еще один вариант, возможно вам подойдет.